# Statistics and Fangraphs

Tags: statistics, graphing-functions

The popular site [fangraphs](https://www.fangraphs.com) updates winning percentages live for MLB games. It creates a graph of how its changed throughout the game, changing after every play. I was wondering, if you average all points on all the graphs, what would *that* graph look like. So my question basically is, without considering that the home team is always put on one side, would it just be a straight line at 50% because of law of large numbers, or is there potentially a factor that would affect this.

This is an example of what a low scoring game's graph looks like.
[image: This is an example of what a low scoring game's graph looks like.]

A great example of what a wild game's graph looks like.
[image: A great example of what a wild game's graph looks like.]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "winning percentages" (at least not to me, I don't follow baseball). Are these betting odds being offered by a gambling site?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said chances to win, as winning percentages implies a teams record. That middle line is where a team has a 50% chance to win the game solely based on the events, not the teams strengths. As you can see, both games end at 100% or 0% for either team. This is not a gambling site.